# SharePoint 2016 search not crawling on SSL site

Tags: sharepoint

We have configured the SSL on SharePoint 2016 environment, however the search crawl is not working on SSL URL site. It works for internal HTTP URL though. I tried the below article but no luck:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2013/02/20/beware-crawling-the-non-default-zone-for-a-sharepoint-2013-web-application/

https://blogit.create.pt/miguelisidoro/2018/08/10/sharepoint-2016-problems-crawling-content-and-the-the-crawler-could-not-communicate-with-the-server-error/

Please let me know if anyone else has faced same issue and resolved it.